# Decision Tree English Rules and Dependency Network in MS SSAS

Tags: machine-learning, ssas, classification, decision-tree

I created a Decision Tree model in Microsoft Analysis Services (SSAS, Visual Studio 2010). There are two tabs in the Mining Model Viewer tab: (1) Decision Tree that shows a tree itself, and (2) Dependency Network that shows the chart of most important variables.

[image]

On the Decision Tree tab I can click on each individual leaf and see the English Rule for that leaf. Is there a way to get ALL the rules at once as a list with the case numbers?

The Dependency Network tab has a slider that you can move to see which variables influence the decision tree most. Is it possible to get ALL important variables as a list with their "importance" number?

Comment: For questions on using databases, dba.stackexchange.com is more appropriate. Because you cannot really *program* in SSAS. A good question for this web site should involve some source code.

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse. I will post it on dba.stackexchange.com as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get the **list of ALL English Rules** from the Mining Structure.

```
SELECT * FROM [MyModel].CONTENT WHERE [CHILDREN_CARDINALITY] = 0
```

**[CHILDREN_CARDINALITY] = 0** defines the DT leaves only.

The following links may be helpful: [Decision Trees Model Query Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645903.aspx), [Mining Model Content for Decision Tree Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645758.aspx)

**"FLATTENED"** keyword will split [NODE_DISTRIBUTION] outcomes into separate rows.

```
SELECT FLATTENED [MODEL_CATALOG],[MODEL_NAME],[NODE_CAPTION],[CHILDREN_CARDINALITY],[NODE_DESCRIPTION],[NODE_PROBABILITY],[NODE_DISTRIBUTION],[NODE_SUPPORT] FROM [MyModel].CONTENT WHERE [CHILDREN_CARDINALITY] = 0 ORDER BY [NODE_SUPPORT] DESC
```